# extract answer from multiple choice question based on user input

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application

**The problem:**
user enters an answer (a,b,c,d). the program should match from database and get the exact full answer.

**Example:**

```
What is 9 + 1?
a. 9
b. 10
c. 5
d. 21
```

When user writes (b) the program should get the answer which is (10)

**here is what i did:**

```
private string Answer(string question, string answer)
        {
            string userans = null;
            try
            {
                if (question != null || answer != null)
                {

                    string[] inputSplit = question.ToString().Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    for (int i = 0; i < inputSplit.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (inputSplit[i].Contains(answer + "."))
                        {
                            userans = inputSplit[i].Split('.')[1];
                            return userans;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            userans = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return userans;
        }
```

**The question is:**
How i can avoid using Loop and extract the same result?. or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString` on `question`?  It's already a `string`.

Comment: @juharr it's a habit i picked from the school.

Comment: An Object Oriented approach would eliminate loops and make everything simpler: A class with a Question, N answers and an indicator which is the correct one. Correct database storage may offer even more learning opportunities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Regex to create groups for each multiple choice option and then extract the answer that way.

This solutions assumes you only ever have 4 options and uses the format you used in the question. You will also want to add some input validation but this is the general idea.

```
public string GetAnswer(string question, string userAnswer)
{
    var regexPattern = "a\\. (\\w+)\r\nb\\. (\\w+)\r\nc\\. (\\w+)\r\nd\\. (\\w+)";
    var match = Regex.Match(question, regexPattern);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        switch (userAnswer)
        {
            case "a":
                return match.Groups[1].Value;

            case "b":
                return match.Groups[2].Value;

            case "c":
                return match.Groups[3].Value;

            case "d":
                return match.Groups[4].Value;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Failed to parse the question.");
}
```

Comment: Group group = Regex.Match(question, "a",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

you mean this way? if not please provide an example

Comment: This solution addresses the question you originally asked but I think a better solution would be to create a class with some properties like ```public string Question``` and ```public List<string> PossibleAnswers``` and then have the user enter the integer index for the multiple choice answer. Then you could extract the answer from the List using the index.

Comment: true, but this wont be used a lot because some users enter the question and other answer it so im using this to fill the database with these question instead of doing it manually.